# Exclude a folder from webpack

Tags: webpack

I have a subproject within my app that contains a file that does not compile: `misc/index.ts`

How can I make webpack totally ignore that file or folder?

**How to reproduce**

```
webpack --mode development
```

**Expected behavior**

Webpack works successfully, as it would do if the `misc` folder did not exist.

**Actual behavior**

Webpack complains about `misc/index.ts` not compiling.

**Additional notes**

The file `misc/index.ts` is required nowhere.

The file `misc/index.ts` does not compile on purpose, because I want webpack to ignore that folder, completely.

Ideally, I would want to tell webpack to **opt-in** some files, rather than exclude some files.

**Project structure**

```
.
├── misc
│   └── index.ts
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── README.md
├── src
│   └── index.ts
├── tsconfig.json
└── webpack.config.js
```

You can try it at https://github.com/sguillia/webpack-exclude: just clone and do `npm run build`

**What I have tried**

I found no option to make webpack ignore a folder.

The exclude rule does not decide which files are being parsed by webpack as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43947834/webpack-exclude-folder).

I had no success with `module.noParse` either.

**webpack.config.js**

```
//@ts-check

"use strict"

const path = require("path")

/**@type {import('webpack').Configuration}*/
const config = {
    target: "node",

    entry: "./src/index.ts",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: "bundle.js",
        libraryTarget: "commonjs",
        devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: "../[resource-path]",
    },
    devtool: "source-map",
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts"],
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "ts-loader",
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                exclude: /misc/,
            },
        ],
    },
}
module.exports = config
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem happened with Typescript too (`tsc -p .`)

Solution in **tsconfig.json**:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

That way, I can opt-in files.